# Does "real-time" constraints prevent the use of a task scheduler?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

By task scheduler I mean any implementation of worker threads pool which distribute work to the threads according to whatever algorithm they are designed with. (like Intel TBB)

I know that "real-time" constraints imply that work gets done in predictable time (I'm not talking about speed). So my guess is that using a task scheduler, which, as far as I know, can't guarantee that some task will be executed before a given time, makes the application impossible to use in these constraints.

Or am I missing something? Is there a way to have both? Maybe by forcing assumptions on the quantity of data that can be processed? Or maybe there are predictable task schedulers?

I'm talking about "hard" real time constraints, not soft real time (like video games).

To clarify:

It is known that there are features in C++ that are not possible to use in this kind of context: new, delete, throw, dynamic_cast. They are not predictable (you don't know how much time can be spent on one of these operations, it depends on too much parameters that are not even known before execution).
You can't really use them in real time contexts. 
What I ask is, does task schedulers have the same unpredictability that would make them unusable in real-time applications?

Comment: You just need to use a task scheduler that *can* guarentee tasks will be executed in time.  Such a task scheduler is usually called a real-time task scheduler.

Comment: I would put it even stronger - 'real time' constraints mandate the use of a preemptive task scheduler, (with real-time guaranteees, as explained by @ChrisDodd).

Answer (score 3):

The term real-time is quite flexible. "Hard real-time" tends to mean things where a few tens of microseconds make the difference between "works right" and "doesn't work right. Not all "real-time" systems require that sort of real-time-ness.

I once worked on a radio-base-station for mobile phones. One of the devices on the board had an interrupt that fired every 2-something milliseconds. For correct operation (not losing calls), we had to deal with the interrupt, that is, do the work inside the interrupt and write the hardware registers with the new values, within 100 microseconds - if we missed, there would be dropped calls. If the interrupt wasn't taken after 160 microseconds, the system would reboot. That is "hard real-time", especially as the processor was just running at a few tens of MHz.

If you produce a video-player, it requires real-time in the a few milliseconds range.

A "display stock prices" probably can be within the 100ms range.

For a webserver it is probably acceptable to respond within 1-2seconds without any big problems.

Also, there is a difference between "worst case worse than X means failure" (like the case above with 100 microseconds or dropped calls - that's bad if it happens more than once every few weeks - and even a few times a year is really something that should be fixed). This is called "Hard real-time".

But other systems, missing your deadline means "Oh, well, we have to do that over again" or "a frame of video flickered a bit", as long as it doesn't happen very often, it's probably OK. This is called "soft real-time".

A lot of modern hardware will make "hard real-time" (the 10s or 100 microsecond range) difficult, because the graphics processor will simply stop the processor from accessing memory, or if the processor gets hot, the `stopclk` pin is pulled for 100 microseconds...

Most modern OS's, such as Linux and Windows, aren't really meant to be "hard real-time". There are sections of code that does disable interrupt for longer than 100 microseconds in some parts of these OS's.

You can almost certainly get some good "soft real-time" (that is, missing the deadline isn't a failure, just a minor annoyance) out of a mainstream modern OS with modern hardware. It'll probably require either modifications to the OS or a dedicated real-time OS (and perhaps suitable special hardware) to make the system do hard real-time.

But only a few things in the world requires that sort of hard real-time. Often the hard real-time requirements are dealt with by hardware - for example, the next generation of radio-base-stations that I described above, had more clever hardware, so you just needed to give it the new values within the next 2-something milliseconds, and you didn't have the "mad rush to get it done in a few tens of microseconds". In a modern mobile phone, the GSM or UMTS protocol is largely dealt with by a dedicated DSP (digital signal processor).

A "hard real-time" requirement is where the system is really failing if a particular deadline (or set of deadlines) can't be met, even if the failure to meet deadlines happens only once. However, different systems have different systems have different sensitivity to the actual time that the deadline is at (as Jerry Coffin mentions). It is almost certainly possible to find cases where a commercially available general purpose OS is perfectly adequate in dealing with the real-time requirements of a hard real-time system. It is also absolutely sure that there are other cases where such hard real-time requirements are NOT possible to meet without a specialized system.

I would say that if you want sub-millisecond guarantees from the OS, then Desktop Windows or Linux are not for you. This is really down to the overall philosophy of the OS and scheduler design, and to build a hard real-time OS requires a lot of thought about locking and potential for one thread to block another thread, from running, etc.

I don't think there is ONE answer that applies to your question. Yes, you can certainly use thread-pools in a system that has hard real-time requirements. You probably can't do it on a sub-millisecond basis unless there is specific support for this in the OS. And you may need to have dedicated threads and processes to deal with the highest priority real-time behaviour, which is not part of the thread-pool itself.

Sorry if this isn't saying "Yes" or "No" to your answer, but I think you will need to do some research into the actual behaviour of the OS, and see what sort of guarantees it can give (worst case). You will also have to decide what is the worse case scenario, and what happens if you miss a deadline - are (lots of) people dying (plane falling out of the sky), or are some banker going to lose millions, is the green lights going to come on at the same time on two directions on a road crossing or is it some bad sound coming out of a speaker?

Comment: I have always heard the term you call "medium real-time" called "soft real-time". Windows desktop can do soft real-time via the [SetPriortyClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, at the `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS` level it will have priority over windows' own interrupts. If you want hard real-time and windows you can go with [3rd party thread scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntervalZero), Microsoft even points to them [on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838583%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx)

Comment: BTW a video-player is not a `hard real time` but rather a `soft real time` meaning, if the deadlines are missed, there will be degradation in the output. In the case of video player or any video decoder, if the deadline is missed, there would be dropped packets, macroblocking in the output, etc.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: REAL_TIME_PRIORITY_CLASS does not give priority over interrupts - that would mean that "for(;;) ;" in a REAL_TIME_PRIORITY_CLASS would not get mouse updates or timer ticks - which I know it does. Windows CE is capable of something pretty close to hard real-time, but if you compare it with a "true hard real-time OS", then it will not be a match - a bit like saying a BMW M3 is good sports car (it is!), but it isn't a match if you compare it with a Formula 1 car.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: From MSDN: "You should almost never use REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS, because this interrupts system threads that manage mouse input, keyboard input, and background disk flushing. This class can be appropriate for applications that "talk" directly to hardware or that perform brief tasks that should have limited interruptions." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It clearly states that this is the "system threads that deal with" - so that's the system threads that take the input from mouse or keyboard and feed it to the app...

Comment: Windows CE is not hard real time out of the box, it is soft real time, but there is a hard real time module see the MSDN link I posted in my first comment.

Comment: The REAL_TIME_PRIORITY_CLASS is the higehst priority, and it locks other `threads` out of action, but it does NOT block interrupts. Which is what you said.

Comment: I admit I misunderstood the exact quote you pasted when I was researching my original comment. You are correct, it blocks the system threads, not the interrupts themselves.

Comment: And that's basically because the system threads are running at a lower priority, and even tho' the Windows system will run threads at lower priority from time to time, if you have something chewing away at really high priority, it will starve those lower priority tasks.

Comment: I understand what real time is and the difference with soft-real time (maybe I should have made this more clear). My question relate to the "hard" real time part, like your radio example, or an equivalent with a different time parameter constraints but still "hard". In this context, I don't see an answer to my question to this question at the moment.

Comment: I've added another edit to the the answer. But no, I'm not able to say exactly whether you can or can't do that - because I don't know enough about what your actual project is.

Comment: Having worked on a "display stock prices" system (a stock exchange where the stock prices were displayed to a large number of identical terminals for traders in different companies), I can say that they care about differences of less than 100ms. Requirements like this impact more than scheduling; you need to be careful that parts of the network don't stop and decide to rebalance their spanning tree. A system view is necessary.

Comment: @MatePeterson I think there is a misunderstanding. I am exactly talking about the kind of contexts you're describing with hard real time. ASSUMING THAT, the question is, is it possible to have task scheduler which are predictable (unlike new, delete, throw and dynamic_cast) so that you can use one in the hard real time context. I'm not talking about "my specific case" and I'm not talking about OS stuffs.

Comment: Under which OS? or do you mean in theory? In theory, sure, why would it be different from any other form of real-time scheduling?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done, but no it's not trivial, and yes there are limits.

You can write the scheduler to guarantee (for example) that an interrupt handler, exception handler (etc.) is guaranteed to be invoked without a fixed period of time from when it occurs. You can guarantee that any given thread will (for example) get at least X milliseconds of CPU time out of any given second (or suitable fraction of a second).

To enforce the latter, you generally need admittance criteria -- an ability for the scheduler to say "sorry, but I can't schedule this as a real-time thread, because the CPU is already under too much load.

In other cases, all it does is guarantee that at least (say) 99% of CPU time will be given the real-time tasks (if any exist) and it's up to whomever designs the system on top of that to schedule few enough real-time tasks that this will ensure they all finish quickly enough.

I feel obliged to add that the "hardness" of real-time requirements is almost entirely orthogonal to the response speed needed. Rather, it's almost entirely about the seriousness of the consequences of being late.

Just for example, consider a nuclear power plant. For a lot of what happens, you're dealing with time periods on the order of minutes, or in some cases even hours. Filling a particular chamber with, say, half a million gallons of water just isn't going to happen in microseconds or milliseconds.

At the same time, the consequences of a later answer can be *huge* -- quite possibly causing not just a few deaths like hospital equipment could, but potentially hundreds or even thousands of deaths, hundreds of millions in damage, etc. As such, it's about as "hard" as real-time requirements get, even though the deadlines are unusually "loose" by most typical standards.

In the other direction, digital audio playback has *much* tighter limits. Delays or dropouts can be quite audible down to a fraction of a millisecond in some cases. At the same time, unless you're providing sound processing for a large concert (or something on that order) the consequences of a dropout will generally be a moment's minor annoyance on the part of a user.

Of course, it's also possible to combine the two -- for an obvious example, in high-frequency trading, deadlines may well be in the order of microseconds (or so) and the loss from missing a deadline could easily be millions or tens of millions of (dollars|euros|pounds|etc.)

Comment: I think this is the answer, it's just not totally clear to me how predictable task scheduler can work.

Answer (score 0):

"Real time" doesn't just mean "fast", it means that the system can respond to meet deadlines in the real world. Those deadlines depend on what you're dealing with in the real world.

Whether or not a task finishes in a particular timeframe is a characteristic of the task, not the scheduler. The scheduler might decide which task gets resources, and if a task hasn't finished by a deadline it might be stopped or have its resource usage constrained so that other tasks can meet their deadlines.

So, the answer to your question is that you need to consider the workload, deadlines and the scheduler together, and construct your system to meet your requirements. There is no magic scheduler that will take arbitrary tasks and make them complete in a predictable time.

Update:

A task scheduler can be used in real-time systems if it provides the guarantees you need. As others have said, there are task schedulers that provide those guarantees.

On the comments: The issue is the upper bound on time taken.

You can use new and delete if you overload them to have the performance characteristics you are after; the problem isn't new and delete, it is dynamic memory allocation. There is no requirement that new and delete use a general-purpose dynamic allocator, you can use them to allocate out of a statically allocated pool sized appropriately for your workload with deterministic behaviour.

On dynamic_cast: I tend not to use it, but I don't think it's performance is non-deterministic to the extent that it should be banned in real-time code. This is an example of the same issue: understanding worst-case performance is important.

Comment: First, I must point that I didn't talk about being fast, I understand the difference. Next I might need to add an example of features C++ I know are not possible to use in this kind of context: new, delete, throw, dynamic_cast. They are not predictable, so you can't really use them in real time contexts. What I ask is, does task schedulers have the same unpredictability that would make them unusable in real-time applications. I'll update my answer.